# Toggle particular pageblocksection for shwoing detail on CheckBox

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a problem like when i select the check box it will rendered the particular part and after i deselect it is not rendering that part which i want to hide.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="DetailLog__c" extensions="checkboxctrl">

 apex:form>

     <apex:pageBlock id="dir">

         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Perosnal Detail">
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.First_Name__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Last_Name__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Email_ID__c}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Date_of_Birth__c}"/>

         </apex:pageBlockSection>

         <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!recheck}" label="Working">
            <apex:actionSupport action="{!reMethod}" event="onclick" reRender="dir"/> 
     </apex:inputCheckbox>

     <apex:outputPanel id="exp">

      <apex:pageBlockSection id="wed" title="Work Experience Detail" rendered="{!if(re==true,true,false)}">

             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Company_Name__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Company_Address__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Joining_Date__c}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Notice_Period_Month__c}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Desgination__c}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Department__c}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
         </apex:outputpanel>
 apex:pageBlockSection title="Additional Information" >

             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Graduation__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Post_Graduation__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.University__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.College_Name__c}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Known_Programming_Languages__c}"/>  
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
     </apex:pageBlock>
/apex:form>
/apex:page>
```

//--------------
Controller

```
public class checkboxctrl {

   public String recheck{get;set;}
   public Boolean re{get;set;}

    public checkboxctrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {



    }

    public PageReference reMethod()
    {


        re=true;
        System.debug('--Re--'+re);
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference reFalseMethod()
    {


        re=false;
        System.debug('--Re--'+re);
        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create another variable in your controller `re`. Also your method `reMethod` is the one that always fire so your value of `re` will always evaluate to true.

Instead you can use the `recheck` value which is the true value of the checkbox.

Just change your `reRender` attribute and things should be good:

```
rendered="{!if(re==true,true,false)}
```

to

```
rendered="{!recheck}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!recheck}" label="Working" onclick="reMethod()" reRender="dir"/>`
<apex:actionFunction name="reMethod" action={!remethod}/>
```

at the place of

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!recheck}" label="Working">
            <apex:actionSupport action="{!reMethod}" event="onclick" reRender="dir"/> 
     </apex:inputCheckbox>
```

//--
**when you click on checkbox you are calling remethod in which you always set re variable True that's why its showing....**

You can do like

```
public PageReference reMethod()
    {

        if(re==true){
             re=false;
        }else{
             re=true;
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `reCheck` variable; you can directly use the `re` variable. This is because `re` is boolean and directly be used with inputcheckbox. That way, you would also not need the 2 methods you have. See below:

Controller Code:

```
public class checkboxctrl {

   public Boolean re{get;set;}

   public checkboxctrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       // Set your Default value here
       re = false;
   }
}
```

Visualforce Code:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="DetailLog__c" extensions="checkboxctrl">

 <apex:form>

     <apex:pageBlock id="dir">

         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Perosnal Detail">
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.First_Name__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Last_Name__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Email_ID__c}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Date_of_Birth__c}"/>

         </apex:pageBlockSection>

         <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!re}" label="Working">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="dir"/> 
         </apex:inputCheckbox>

     <apex:outputPanel id="exp">

      <apex:pageBlockSection id="wed" title="Work Experience Detail" rendered="{!re}">

             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Company_Name__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Company_Address__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Joining_Date__c}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Notice_Period_Month__c}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Desgination__c}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Department__c}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
         </apex:outputpanel>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Additional Information" >

             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Graduation__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Post_Graduation__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.University__c}"/>
             <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.College_Name__c}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!DetailLog__c.Known_Programming_Languages__c}"/>  
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
     </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```